# Swift - Making CoreData for Course and Tasks Models

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working on `CoreData` for my practice tute task on Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.2.1). The app was working properly at the first increment which did not require `CoreData`.

Now I need to extend it and create a `CoreData` Model but I dont know if I am doing the right way for the following scenario:

- In VC1: there is a Table View Controller showing courses on each row. A course includes `courseCode`, `courseTitle`, `courseDesc`, `numOfTask`. When tapping on a row of a course, the app moves to VC2.
- In VC2: all tasks of the selected course will display here in a Table View Controller. A task includes `taskTitle`, `taskTag`, `dueDate`. It should show the tasks belong to the selected course only.

I have these 2 models to manage data in each VC individually:

[image]
[image]

But how to determine which tasks belong to a specific course using `CoreData`? You guys please suggest me a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the entity `Course` of Course Model, add another attribute to indicate to which course the task belongs to: `forCourse: String?`

Then to display only specific tasks for a course, after fetching `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve data to `ManagedObjectContext`, check the course to display relevant tasks